# dpdk-dumpcap not capturing incoming packets on the port

Tags: c, networking, packet, dpdk, nic

I have two nic cards with 2 QSFP28 ports, and internally port is configured to 4 so each nic card has 8 ports, i have a cable connected to nic card each other,

[image]

now i am transmitting packets from pcap file using tcpreplay on  2nd nic card where ports are binded to kernel driver

now on the other nic card i have binded two ports to dpdk and triggered the below commands to capture the packets, which i am not getting any, if i unbind from dpdk driver and put it back to kernel it works with tcpdump

1. build/app/dpdk-testpmd -c 0xf0 -n 4 -- -i --port-topology=chained
2. build/app/dpdk-dumpcap -w /tmp/capture.pcapng
   ice_set_rx_function(): Using AVX2 Vector Rx (port 0).
   ice_set_rx_function(): Using AVX2 Vector Rx (port 1).
   Capturing on '0000:0f:00.3'
   File: /tmp/capture.pcapng
   Packets captured: 0
3. tcpreplay -i ens5f3 c2_15scs_4_ant_256_frame_128.pcap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be two options of how to fix this:

- replace `-i` ("interactive mode") with `--tx-first` in the `testpmd` command;
- in `testpmd` interactive prompt, type `start tx_first`, press Enter.

Comment: Thank you it worked, i am very new to usage of DPDK, I have couple of questions
1. what was wrong in my first method of testing?
2. if I am send a packet to the receiving port and the packet's destination address doesn't match, it will get dropped?
3.  is there any way to get the runtime dpdk logs of what's happening?

Comment: okay got it, 
1. for the testcase where i have a now i will bind one of the above port say0f.03 to dpdk driver and trigger the dpdk-dumpcap on the port to capture, then the other port say 05.03 present on different NIC Card is binded to kernel driver but connected to 0f.03 through QSFP cable, if i send packets from 05.03 through tcpreplay i dont get any packets captured at 0f.03 why?

Comment: 3. all these logs are stored in some file location?

Comment: please see the latest answer

Answer (score 0):

@user23509140
Please find the below execution ens2f3 is binded to DPDK driver
[image]

[image]

Comment: please see the below answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@user10304260

I have binded two ports to dpdk one is port0 and port1 also physically connected to each other by cable, i executed start on one testpmd terminal and in another linux  terminal i did dpdk-dumpcap, even after this i am not getting any packets captured,  in testpmd after i do stop i can see the stats of stream which are all zeros

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following sequence:

1. testpmd interactive
2. port stop all
3. set promisc all on
4. port start all
5. set fwd rxonly
6. start
7. tcpdump -i ens5f3 on seperate terminal

I did not get any packets captured

[image]

Comment: sure, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78132869/packets-not-getting-transmitted-from-dpdk-port-to-kernel-port